# Metadata in Ektron missing dot character

Tags: metadata, ektron

I am trying to add metadata to Ektron content, follow their instruction [Working with Metadata Definitions] http://documentation.ektron.com/cms400/v802/WebHelp/Managing%20Content/Content%20Properties/content_MetaData_metadata_definitions.htm#content_MetaData_metadata_definitions_1628974798_496196 But whatever I do, I can not put the dot character (.) in. After I click Save, the dot character disappear. Does anyone know how to overcome this?

Comment: In what field are you putting the period (.)? Can you provide a screenshot for what you are trying to save?

Comment: I tried to put some description in the default metadata 'Description' like: 'Test1. Test2'. But after click Save, only 'Test1 Test2' remains

Comment: Again - a screenshot with *exactly* what you're trying to configure would be helpful.

Comment: Hi egandalf, this is the screenshot of what I am doing https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/79749349/EktronMetadata.png after I click Save, the 'Test1. Test2' become 'Test1 Test2'

Comment: Can you also show how exactly the metadata field is configured?

Answer (score 2):

We were having this problem in Ektron 8.5 we upgraded to Ektron 8.7 and punctuation is allowed in metadata fields.